# sensor position amcl

Tags: navigation, sensor, scanner, position, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

how i can tell AMCL the position of my laserscanner? the sensor is not in the centre of the robot. so everytime the robot turns, the amcl loses the orientation.

Thank you very much!
Link

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257062/sensor-position-amcl/) by [link1609](https://answers.ros.org/users/29009/link1609/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That information should be present in your TF tree, so you should not need to explicitly tell amcl what that transform is.

The LaserScan messages that amcl subscribes to should have a frame id in the header of each message. amcl will then transform the data in the scan message from the message frame id, to whatever frame is specified in the amcl parameter `base_frame_id`. The transform predicted by amcl (i.e. your pose in the global frame) will hence be relative to the `base_frame_id`.

So, make sure you are publishing transforms from your scanner frame id, to the base frame id, and that those transforms represent the appropriate offset of the physical scanner from the base frame (where the base frame origin should be the centre of rotation of your robot).

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0